# I can't create database by user input in python

Tags: python-3.x

1.Getting problem in creating databases by taking user input

```
table_name = input("Enter the Table name : ")
attribute_1 = input('Enter the First Attribute : ')
type_1 = input('Enter the type for the first attribute : ')
attribute_2 = input('Enter the Second attribute : ')
type_2= input('Enter the type for Second attribute : ')
sql1 = 'CREATE TABLE',table_name,'(',attribute_1,'',type_1,'', attribute_2,'', type_2,')'
cur.execute(sql1)
db.commit()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Include all relevant error messages in your post.

Comment: You aware of https://xkcd.com/327/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concatenate strings using commas in Python. You should instead use the `str.join` method. Also note that there should be a comma in the SQL string between attributes:

```
sql1 = ' '.join(('CREATE TABLE',table_name,'(',attribute_1,'',type_1,',', attribute_2,'', type_2,')'))
```